# How to fix "(110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream" (504 errors) in nginx log?

Tags: nginx, server, timeout, php-5.6, nginx-config

Over the past few days a TON of timeouts started appearing in the nginx logs out of the blue and after a lot of troubleshooting I haven't gotten anywhere.

**Here are some specs:** 
The server is Ubuntu 14.04, running Nginx 1.4.6 and PHP 5.6. The application (though not entirely relevant to this problem) is running on Laravel 5.2. Physical specs for the server are 2 cpus & 8 GB memory. I can have anywhere from 50 to 100 users on the site at a time, and I'm expecting it to grow in the near future. 
I've tried to add, increase and decrease the timeouts, added buffers, added `fastcgi_keep_conn on;`, and turned the access.log off to decrease used resources. I've also mirrored the required changes in the appropriate places across my nginx.conf, sites-enabled/site.conf, and php.ini. However these timeouts just keep happening. There are a few requests in my application that are very heavy on the server (large SQL requests, large API requests and the like) and these are the ones that the timeouts always occur on.

**nginx.conf:**

```
events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    # tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off; # do not expose nginx version

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    server_names_hash_max_size 512;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 30M;

    # Timeouts
    # keepalive_timeout 15;
    # send_timeout 15;
    # client_header_timeout 15;
    # client_body_timeout 15;

    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

    fastcgi_buffering on;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 16k;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 1024m;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**sites-enabled/site.conf:**

```
# non-ssl to ssl
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com api.site.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name site.com api.site.com;
    root /home/user/sites/site.com/public;

    listen 443; # LISTEN PORT MARKER

    # SSL PLACEHOLDERS
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/site.com/2019/crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/site.com/2019/key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # disable SSLv3

    charset utf-8;

    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    access_log  off;
    # access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.com-access.log; # uncomment to enable
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/site.com-error.log error;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\. { deny all; }

    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        client_body_buffer_size 10k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_buffering on;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 16k;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 1024m;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    }
}
```

The thing is, I'm a web developer not a sysadmin. I've been flying blind here, trying to throw darts at a board that I can barely see. I'm not sure if I've done everything right and all I need is to upgrade my server and/or optimize my requests or if my nginx configuration is absolutely awful.